# Error when compiling with Tex Live 2015: eledmac package

Tags: texlive, eledmac

I've just recently upgraded to Tex Live 2015 and I have several files using eledmac package. With the new distribution I get this error in my .log file:

```
    /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:84: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \reserveinserts 

l.84 \reserveinserts
                    {32}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:84: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.84 \reserveinserts{3
                      2}
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/ragged2e.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty))
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:98: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \reserveinserts 

l.98 \reserveinserts
                    {32}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:98: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.98 \reserveinserts{3
                      2}
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eledmac/eledmac.sty:3294: No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3294 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}

)
```

It's obviously related to eledmac package. Any hints on how can I get this fixed?

Thanks

Comment: an update for that went to ctan I'm sure (doesn't seem to have made it to tl update yet) for now you can just do `\def\reseveinserts#1{}` so the error goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install the last version of eledmac which is in the CTAN, or wait for install by tlmgr. That is linked to the change of etoolbox behavior with the last version LaTeX 2015. It has been fixed, but between the frozen of TeXLive 2014 and the release of TeXLive2015.

you can also add

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

before loading eledmac.

Answer (score 1):

I have approximatively the same problem. I use a recent version of MikTeX and when I compile with XeLaTeX I obtain the same error message as fdiog.

I have created an updated `eledmac.sty` from the latest version of the package. It did not solve the problem for me. Neither when I added `\usepackage{etex}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.